# Spring Boot2 and Netflix Zuul

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, netflix

Someone  already set up  Spring Boot 2 Release and spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul?

If I add this dependency in pom file then I have a runtime error: `NoSuchFieldError: BINDER_BEAN_NAME`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because of dependency management.

Trying adding the dependency management in `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
   <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M7</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, you should add an explanation so people can understand what the problem is and how your answer can help solve it.

Comment: Thank you.  I used Finchley.M7 and spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul dependency for ZuulFilter.

Comment: Happy to help :)